# How do 256 java bytecodes translate to everything java does (graphics, IO, etc)

Tags: java, bytecode

I'm looking at java bytecode listings and Wikipedia, and they all seem to be basic operations (branch, push, pop, cast, etc.). And many articles use these basic examples. But what happens when I read a line from the console, or create a new JButton? Where's the bytecode for opening a port?

I believe I saw something for "making a system call" (although I didn't find it today, skimming through the list several times). Do these "special" calls have their own code, which are directly delegated (don't know how to say it technically) to the OS by the VM? I know there are ways to open up the bytecode, but I'm looking for a general explanation, not weeks of learning advanced bytecode.

Comment: How does (a limited) number of op-codes translate to everything a CPU does? How does (a limited) number of math operators translate to an unlimited number of Algebra equations? How does (a finite) set of words translate to a [near?] infinite set of phrases?

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke

Comment: You might want to learn a bit about assembly language and opcodes. The set of instructions is rather small, yet so much can be derived from it.

Comment: Related to your second paragraph: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Comment: **pst, drum** The same mathematical operators in Java can do all that, but how does pushing and popping values off a stack start painting pixels? I can imagine a bunch of bytecode manipulating a String, represented by a sequence of chars, but again nothing related to IO? **At Hunter** I'm reading it but not seeing the connection :P I'm not so wondering about how 256 bytecodes have a ton of possibilities vs. what actually happens. **At Paul** I'm also reading it but I'm not sure if it's appropriate: I'm curious as two how this limitted bytecode does everything, not writing native code myself

Comment: @Raekye All that is required to *theoretically* solve the same set of problems is [Turing Completeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) (*and* the ability to access the same resources). Of course, just because a language is TC doesn't make it practical. But, a CPU and the JVM work on the same model. (Note that the JVM needs to delegate some operations to JNI: *actual* I/O - e.g. external resource - operations are a good example of when the JVM delegates to the applicable Native interfaces.)

Comment: @Raekye A CPU uses memory mapped IO. For example your monitor is an output device which has been mapped to the CPU's memory. By accessing that memory address you can manipulate the monitor's pixels. That you can easily do using assembly (of course, complex animations will be complicated).

Comment: @drum interesting (never thought of it that way), but earlier I read that the JVM makes sure a program doesn't access not-it's own memory. Technical question then, can the bytecode directly access this memory, or is it done through a native class?

Comment: I do not know the details, but the JNI was written by a language like C/C++ which CAN access memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no byte code for opening a port or drawing graphics to the screen. There are classes that perform these tasks. These classes have native methods, those are methods written in C (or any other language that can be compiled to a native library) and as they are native, they can access the network and graphcis libraries of your operating system to perform those tasks. So you are instantiating these classes and call some of their methods. Java Byte Code offers byte code for instantiating classes and for calling methods of objects. If the JVM sees that this is a native method, it will call the native code that belongs to this method and this native code can do pretty much anything a C or C++ program could do.

So for example, if you call `System.out.println` in Java, *roughly* the following happens:

`System` is a class with a static variable `out`. This variable points to an object of type `java.io.PrintStream` which has already been created by the JVM before your `main` method is ever executed. The `out` variable is initialized like this:

```
FileOutputStream fdOut = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
setOut0(new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fdOut, 128), true));
```

And the method setOut0 is defined as

```
private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);
```

This means setOut0 is a native method, written in C, or some other language that can be compiled and linked to a native library, though at least the interface between Java and this library is usually written in C.

Java will search in all loaded libraries for a symbol (in that case symbol means function name) with the name `Java_java_lang_System_setOut0`, this is `Java_ClassName_MethodName` and call it. A sample C code I have found for this method looked like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_lang_System_setOut0(JNIEnv *env, jclass cla, jobject stream)
{
    jfieldID fid =
        (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env,cla,"out","Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
    if (fid == 0)
        return;
    (*env)->SetStaticObjectField(env,cla,fid,stream);
}
```

Yet this is not the real magic, the real magic happens elsewhere. `PrintStream.write()` calls `BufferedWriter.write()`. This method again calls `OutputStreamWriter.write()` (not directly, but sooner or later it ends up there) and this method calls `StreamEncoder.write()`. Wow, it's getting hard to trace that call. The `StreamEncoder` calls `BufferedOutputStream.write()`, this one calls `FileOutputStream.write()` and this one calls `FileOutputStream.writeBytes()` and finally, finally we are there! `FileOutputStream.writeBytes()` is a *native method*. It will look something like this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_java_io_FileOutputStream_writeBytes(JNIEnv *env,
    jobject this, jbyteArray bytes, jint off, jint len) {
    writeBytes(env, this, bytes, off, len, fos_fd);
}
```

So it calls a function named writeBytes and this function looks different depending on your operating system, e.g. whether this is Windows, Linux or OS X. On UNIX/Linux systems this function may call another function (and so on), but somewhere is a simple C function call to write something to a C `FILE *` stream or a file descriptor (which is just an `int` in C). So it could be a `printf()/fprintf()` or a `puts()/fputs()` call that writes to `stdout` or a `write()` call that writes to `STDOUT_FILENO`. In Windows it is usually a call to `WriteFile()`, though it could also be a `printf()/fprintf()` (those are C standard functions, all platforms must support them).

Comment: So when I call `System.out.println` what actually happens? What bytecode begins the native code? (I'm about to disect it but I'm also interested in how all the mappings work)

Comment: Edit: So I see `GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream`. I'm guessing the JVM sorta listens for native classes, and deals with those function calls separately?

Comment: If you want the really fine grain details, you should learn about microprocessors first. To geto to Java, several layers of abstractions have been done.

Comment: `If the JVM sees that this is a native method, it will call the native C code` ah that was the bit I missed. I've touched on assembly, but was mainly curious where the "more complex" bytecode came in. Anyways, that clears it up for me. Thanks for the great responses and links!

Comment: @Raekye I'll update a question regarding System.out.println, it's a good example :-)

Comment: @Mecki wow thanks for the detailed explanation! Could not upvote enough. Where did you trace all these method calls? :P

Comment: @Raekye I trace those calls by looking at the source code. All this stuff is OpenSource. Search for `OpenJDK` on Google. OpenJDK is an OpenSource JDK implementation that is based upon the official JDK source code as released by Oracle themselves.